# bootstrap login /img/glyphicons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble with boostrap-responsive.

When I login to my application on my laptop I get the homepage `localhost:8080/abc/` with no problems but when I log into the same app from any mobile device it goes to `ip:8080/abc/img/glyphicons-halflings.png`. And just displays all bootstraps icons on the page.

If I manually put in the correct url after, the app works fine and if I logout and log back in it works fine. Always occurs the first time you try to log in. Below is the code I am using in my jsp. I have done a search for "`img/glyphicons-halflings.png`" in my project and the only place it occurs is in the bootstrap code so I cannot understand why it redirects to this page.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ABC</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="<c:url value="/css/bootstrap.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<c:url value="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is not from the bootstrap, you just need to set the absolute url.

create an helper class contains static method called `baseUrl` (or whatever) which return a base url of your website.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody has a similar issue, the problem was actually with my spring-security.xml. There was a typo on the part to permitAll() to view the images folder. So my understanding of it is that when bootstrap attempted to access the images folder for the mobile site(not used on desktop version), spring security intercepted this and redirected to the login page which was normal behaviour. Then when I would login spring was redirecting back to the request bootstrap had made before the login and that is why all the glyphicons were being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "glyphicons" are not just CSS, they need other ressources more than js and css, which is the "fonts" this ressources  comes whith "js" and "css" folders  in the bootstrap framework, 
Now for making all this working to gather  just  copy the "fonts" folder in the same level of  your "css" and "js"  in your Java EE project.
Thanks.